# How to create a battery level indicator in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, batterylevel

[image]

I want to create a battery level indicator as in the image(which i circled). The green part should fill based on the available battery in the device.

Getting the battery percentage from the device like this

```
registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

So in the layout i am able to display the battery percentage.

```
public class BatteryIndicatorActivity extends Activity {
        //Create Broadcast Receiver Object along with class definition
    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
          //When Event is published, onReceive method is called
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
              //Get Battery %
            int level = i.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfield);
              //Set TextView with text
            tv.setText("Battery Level: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%");
        }

    };
```

But how to create a UI for this type of battery indicator. Is their any api to achieve this?, If not how to create such type of UI.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my CustomView for display battery level

```
class BatteryView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) :
    View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var radius: Float = 0f
    private var isCharging: Boolean = false

    // Top
    private var topPaint =
        PaintDrawable(Color.WHITE) // I only want to corner top-left and top-right so I use PaintDrawable instead of Paint
    private var topRect = Rect()
    private var topPaintWidthPercent = 50
    private var topPaintHeightPercent = 8

    // Border
    private var borderPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLUE
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }
    private var borderRect = RectF()
    private var borderStrokeWidthPercent = 8
    private var borderStroke: Float = 0f

    // Percent
    private var percentPaint = Paint()
    private var percentRect = RectF()
    private var percentRectTopMin = 0f
    private var percent: Int = 0

    // Charging
    private var chargingRect = RectF()
    private var chargingBitmap: Bitmap? = null

    init {
        init(attrs)
        chargingBitmap = getBitmap(R.drawable.ic_charging)
    }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BatteryView)
        try {
            percent = ta.getInt(R.styleable.BatteryView_bv_percent, 0)
            isCharging = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.BatteryView_bv_charging, false)
        } finally {
            ta.recycle()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val measureWidth = View.getDefaultSize(suggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec)
        val measureHeight = (measureWidth * 1.8f).toInt()
        setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth, measureHeight)

        radius = borderStroke / 2
        borderStroke = (borderStrokeWidthPercent * measureWidth).toFloat() / 100

        // Top
        val topLeft = measureWidth * ((100 - topPaintWidthPercent) / 2) / 100
        val topRight = measureWidth - topLeft
        val topBottom = topPaintHeightPercent * measureHeight / 100
        topRect = Rect(topLeft, 0, topRight, topBottom)

        // Border
        val borderLeft = borderStroke / 2
        val borderTop = topBottom.toFloat() + borderStroke / 2
        val borderRight = measureWidth - borderStroke / 2
        val borderBottom = measureHeight - borderStroke / 2
        borderRect = RectF(borderLeft, borderTop, borderRight, borderBottom)

        // Progress
        val progressLeft = borderStroke
        percentRectTopMin = topBottom + borderStroke
        val progressRight = measureWidth - borderStroke
        val progressBottom = measureHeight - borderStroke
        percentRect = RectF(progressLeft, percentRectTopMin, progressRight, progressBottom)

        // Charging Image
        val chargingLeft = borderStroke
        var chargingTop = topBottom + borderStroke
        val chargingRight = measureWidth - borderStroke
        var chargingBottom = measureHeight - borderStroke
        val diff = ((chargingBottom - chargingTop) - (chargingRight - chargingLeft))
        chargingTop += diff / 2
        chargingBottom -= diff / 2
        chargingRect = RectF(chargingLeft, chargingTop, chargingRight, chargingBottom)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        drawTop(canvas)
        drawBody(canvas)
        if (!isCharging) {
            drawProgress(canvas, percent)
        } else {
            drawCharging(canvas)
        }
    }

    private fun drawTop(canvas: Canvas) {
        topPaint.bounds = topRect
        topPaint.setCornerRadii(floatArrayOf(radius, radius, radius, radius, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f))
        topPaint.draw(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawBody(canvas: Canvas) {
        borderPaint.strokeWidth = borderStroke
        canvas.drawRoundRect(borderRect, radius, radius, borderPaint)
    }

    private fun drawProgress(canvas: Canvas, percent: Int) {
        percentPaint.color = getPercentColor(percent)
        percentRect.top = percentRectTopMin + (percentRect.bottom - percentRectTopMin) * (100 - percent) / 100
        canvas.drawRect(percentRect, percentPaint)
    }

    // todo change color
    private fun getPercentColor(percent: Int): Int {
        if (percent > 50) {
            return Color.WHITE
        }
        if (percent > 30) {
            return Color.YELLOW
        }
        return Color.RED
    }

    private fun drawCharging(canvas: Canvas) {
        chargingBitmap?.let {
            canvas.drawBitmap(it, null, chargingRect, null)
        }
    }

    private fun getBitmap(drawableId: Int, desireWidth: Int? = null, desireHeight: Int? = null): Bitmap? {
        val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId) ?: return null
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            desireWidth ?: drawable.intrinsicWidth,
            desireHeight ?: drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }

    fun charge() {
        isCharging = true
        invalidate() // can improve by invalidate(Rect)
    }

    fun unCharge() {
        isCharging = false
        invalidate()
    }

    fun setPercent(percent: Int) {
        if (percent > 100 || percent < 0) {
            return
        }
        this.percent = percent
        invalidate()
    }

    fun getPercent(): Int {
        return percent
    }
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="BatteryView">
    <attr name="bv_charging" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="bv_percent" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**drawable/ic_charging.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="368.492"
    android:viewportHeight="368.492">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M297.51,150.349c-1.411,-2.146 -3.987,-3.197 -6.497,-2.633l-73.288,16.498L240.039,7.012c0.39,-2.792 -1.159,-5.498 -3.766,-6.554c-2.611,-1.069 -5.62,-0.216 -7.283,2.054L71.166,217.723c-1.489,2.035 -1.588,4.773 -0.246,6.911c1.339,2.132 3.825,3.237 6.332,2.774l79.594,-14.813l-23.257,148.799c-0.436,2.798 1.096,5.536 3.714,6.629c0.769,0.312 1.562,0.469 2.357,0.469c1.918,0 3.78,-0.901 4.966,-2.517l152.692,-208.621C298.843,155.279 298.916,152.496 297.51,150.349z" />
</vector>
```

**Using**

```
<package.BatteryView
        android:id="@+id/battery_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_charging"
        app:bv_charging="false"
        app:bv_percent="20" />
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Github project](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidBatteryView)

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do it. Here are few of them:

1. Use a `ProgressBar`, make it vertical, make it be drawn in the battery shape
2. Use a custom `View`, override `onDraw()` in it, and draw the battery shape on the `canvas`
3. Use a white image with a transparent battery shape. Place it over a view, where you fill a background vertically, or change background view's height.

Comment: Thank you Vlad.. did their any sample project available which will make a battery indicator soo.

Comment: @AnurajR, I don't think that somebody created a sample specially for a battery indicator

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic battery view/indicator in Kotlin Android

custom view file

```
class BatteryCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
): View(context, attrs) {

    val percentAge = 90

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val paint = Paint().apply {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue)
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }

        val percentageWidth = (width * percentAge) / 100

        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(0f, height.toFloat())
            lineTo(percentageWidth.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
            lineTo(percentageWidth.toFloat(), 0f)
            close()
        }

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        invalidate()
    }
}
```

and in XML where you want to use it

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <com.example.pocforcharts.BatteryCustomView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Wrapping it around card-view is optional of course.