# How to create CustomView for display battery level

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android application with battery status. I want to show the battery status in imageview like an indicator with live updates. Now I can get the status of the battery and it is charging or not, percentage of power using a broadcast receiver. Now I want to display that in the imageview. I am having an empty battery icon. I want to update the icon with colors based on the percentage. I referred to two links. But both tutorials created a canvas and update that canvas. But I want to update in the SVG file. Is it possible? Please give any idea for this issue.

links I followed: 
https://www.rubicon-world.com/blog/2019/05/creating-custom-views-in-android/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415603/2845346

My SVG is:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M344.302,116.256h-34.548v-3.658c0,-13.601 -11.027,-24.634 -24.627,-24.634h-58.248c-13.601,0 -24.624,11.033 -24.624,24.634v3.658h-34.552c-13.601,0 -24.628,11.023 -24.628,24.624v49.172v28.292v181.06c0,13.601 11.028,24.633 24.628,24.633h176.599c13.602,0 24.624,-11.032 24.624,-24.633v-181.06v-28.292V140.88C368.926,127.279 357.904,116.256 344.302,116.256zM344.302,190.052v28.292v181.06H167.703v-181.06v-28.292V140.88h59.176v-28.282h58.248v28.282h59.175V190.052z" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create few icons that you want to use as indicator of battery level, next create new level-list drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_battery_low_level"
        android:maxLevel="15" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_battery_medium_level"
        android:maxLevel="50" />
</level-list>
```

Next when u received a update of % battery changed update the drawable like this:

`batteryImageView.setImageLevel(batteryPercentageValue)`

Comment: Yes. It is a good idea. But I am having two scenarios. If the device is charging then, the display battery icon will contain the charging icon. If it is not charging It will show only the battery icon. For example, If the battery level is 20% then, battery icon color should fill with red color. If charge mode then the same red color with charging icon inside the battery icon. So there are two cases. In these cases how to handle?

Comment: OFC, you can set the drawables as selectors. So add 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_battery_low_level_charging" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_battery_low_level" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>

ad set batteryImageView.isSelected status depends of charging state

Comment: Hi @Ikazuchi.. I think this is also not going to be work. Let me explain my case again. I am having 5 icons for charging and 5 icons for discharging. If the battery is charging and the battery is 50%, then I will show the charging icon with 50% filled. If charger removed I will switch the discharging icon with 50% filled. So for this, it will not work, right? So I planned to create two level-list XML and going to set by runtime based on the charging status. Is that right?

Comment: I am pretty sure it will work.
In the level-list you should add this selector that i gave you example in previous comment. So you will only operate in one level-list element, and to change lvl and charging state you will have to call 2 methods `setImageLevel` and `isSelected`.
To be more specific you will use your selector as drawable so `        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_battery_low_level_selector"`

Comment: Oh. Then I will try and let you know today.

Comment: And what was your result?

Comment: So I need to create 5 selectors.? Right?

Comment: You have to create selector for each state of your battery.

Comment: Yes. It is working. Thank you. Learned a new one..!!

Comment: Great to hear, have fun.